# Fail to clone a repository for encoding?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I'd like to clone a repository from github.com to my Github Desktop, but failed, saying that 'failed to convert http：to ACE, could not convert string to UTF-8'.

[image]

[image]

I think there may be something wrong with encoding. Because at first, my error is a timeout when cloning. I input 'git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080' after google. But unfortunately, I  input Chinese '：'.  But I couldn't correct it when I realized it was Chinese because I 'm not familiar with git commands.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do language check (in git bash):

```
echo $LANG
```

Mine says:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_GB.UTF-8
```

If it is Chinese, try to change it to `en_US` for example with:

`export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: I have check my language and revise it to 'en_GB,UTF-8'. But the error remains. Thank you all the same!